# cannot search for NuGet Packages in visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Cannot search for online NuGet packages in visual studio 2019. Default package source is offline and no option for adding online package source. Searched through the internet. Wasn't able to find the solution.
Please check the image below.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Are you using a proxy server to access the internet?

Answer (score 16):

[image]Change the Package Source to nuget.org, if is not available add it https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json

Answer (score 12):

If you click on the gear to the right of the Package Source drop down, it'll take you into the options for Package Sources. You can then add nuget.org as a package source. For example, I have:

Name: api.nuget.org
Source: https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json