# Visual Studio 2019 Nuget issue

Tags: .net, log4net, visual-studio-2019, nuget-package

I have installed Visual Studio Community edition 2019 from the Microsoft Website.
My Nuget package manager is only installing offline packages.I have tried to install it explicitly from the nuget.org and installing it in my project but is of no help. I also tried to add a package source to nuget.org but faced the same issue. My package sources:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55728564/cannot-search-for-nuget-packages-in-visual-studio-2019

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VS2015 nuget package manager not finding packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36386895/vs2015-nuget-package-manager-not-finding-packages)